# Bootstrap same height column without removing float

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/6cascyr8/

I need the columns to be the same height.

I would normally do this with display table and removoing the float.

The content is created in a loop and sometimes some of the columns in the row are empty like the bottom row in the example.

Becuase the float is removed the the colums are centered.

Is there a way to have columns with the same height without removing the float.

The columns have dynmic content so I can't set there height.

```
    .the-table{
        display:table;
        border-spacing:20px;
    }

    .the-cell{
        color: white;
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        background:red
    }
```

Comment: Does `display: flex` do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/6cascyr8/7/

Comment: flex works but Ideally I would like support for ie9

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS should take care of left aligning the table cells

```
.the-table:before {
    content: normal !important;   
}
```

However, you'll see an alignment problem in the cells because of your `border-spacing: 20px`. Replace that by a combination of (thick white) borders on your cells and perhaps padding on the rows.